# c# pictureBox changes size with font

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

When I change the font of the whole Form with this code:

```
this.Font = new Font("Gravity", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Then all my PictureBoxes (with a size of 16x16) are getting bigger, too.

Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Gravity always wins.

Comment: Why do you change the font of the entire form?
Instead of changing the font of the controls, for example, labels?

Comment: if you dont set the Font Property on the PictureBoxes, they take the font of Container, for prevent this, i suggest set Font Property on all PictureBoxes where you need preserve the size.

Comment: Set the Form `AutoScaleMode` to something different than `Font` if you don't like/manage this behavoiur.

Comment: Actually, most of the time this will not really make a difference; but various system combinations behave differently.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.
The reason why i changed the font on the whole form is, that i liked that it resizes the groupboxes, because it was useful for me in this case.

Comment: @AlpakaJoe Then, try with my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on changing the font of the form, then use

[Control.OnFontChanged Method (EventArgs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onfontchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

This method will be executed every time you change the font of the form, so when it is executed, you can specify that your `PictureBox` (All) will keep the font you have defined.

This is if all your `PictureBox` have the same font:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected override OnFontChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if(control is PictureBox)
            {
               control.Font = new Font(<Your constant defined font>);;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, assuming your pictureboxes have different fonts.

You can store the sources in a list (or also in an array), and each time the source of your form is altered, you simply call the previously stored sources to be reassigned to each `PictureBox`:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Font> PBFonts = new List<Font>();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
        {
           if(control is PictureBox)
           {
               this.PBFonts.Add(control.Font);
           }
        }
    }

    protected override OnFontChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
        {
           if(control is PictureBox picture)
           {
               picture.Font = this.PBFonts[index];
           }
           index++;
        }
    }
}
```